# IPv6対応メールサーバ(Postfix)構築失敗　一部の送信元からメール受信できない

Tags: postfix, ipv6

イントラネットでメールサーバーを構築したのですが、一部送信元からのメール受信ができず困っています。
目的は、レンタルサーバーのメール容量が小さいことに不満があり、IPv6を使って、自前サーバーを構築を試みました。
しかし、メールサーバーの構築に苦労しています。

【環境（バージョン等）】
　・OS：CentOS7　7.4.1708
　・Postfix:2.10.1
　・dovecot:2.2.10

・DNS機能は独自ドメインを取得した「お名前ドットコム」のDNSサーバーを利用しました。
　　もちろん、自営サーバーには、AAAAレコードで記載しています。
　　これにより、Webサーバーとデータベースサーバーは外部から接続できています。
　　したがって、IPv6の名前解決に問題は無いと思います。

【事象（困っていること）】
　テキストやWebの情報に沿って、メールサーバーをインストール（Postfix,Dovecot)しました。
　しかし、Webメールを使って試験したところ、一部の送信元からのメールが受信できないのです。
　受信できる送信元もあることから致命的では無いと思うのですが、この違いの理由がわかりません。
　何らかのアドバイスをいただければ助かります。

［メール受信が成功した送信元］
　　Ｇｍａｉｌ、Ｏｕｔｌｏｏｋ．ｃｏｍ、プロバイダ系（スターキャット、コミュファ光）など
　　　　⇒　/var/log/maillogに着信処理記録が残っています。
　［メール受信が失敗した送信元］
　　ロリポップ、Ｙａｈｏｏ　Ｍａｉｌ、Ｅｘｃｉｔｅなど
　　　　⇒　/var/log/maillogにも、まったく記録が残りません。

【仮説（初歩的見解）】
　受信できない送信元では、IPv6とIPv4のデュアルスタックになっていないのか？
　でも、今時IPv6に対応していないとは思えないので、何かしら特別な設定が必要なのでしょうか？

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: > 今時デュアルスタック対応してないとか    まだまだ珍しくはないと思いますが？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。未だIPv4を前提としているサイトが残っているというわけですね。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/iwaprint4567/items/e1cbc5257fde45367a41